# How do I prepare for not landing a single job as a Junior Android Developer?

Tags: job-search, junior

I'll try and be brief, I finished high school, started college for my bachelor in CS. I've been doing Android dev for over a year and intensely, I've applied to 15 jobs(not all of which were junior level or entry-level as they maybe had a position nevertheless or would just keep me in mind or idk really). Well it has been over a week now and 2 denies only, I am preparing for the worst in which case all 15 are denied or no responses. The thing that bothers me is just that my CV is quite strong, I have a lot of knowledge for and above Junior-level position, I have a couple of interesting projects, and skills that are used in the industry. Now all of that being said, I don't want to give up but I have no idea how to go forward. I already made all the projects I wanted to make and I was really excited to wrap my head around everything I know in a real company while working in teams and getting started on my Android dev career. I have no idea how to do that unless I find a starting point ie. a starting job. I even applied to unpaid internships and everything I could find even tho I strongly oppose being a literal slave but times are rough. Another problem is the simple lack of jobs and internships as well. This is [my Github](https://github.com/Nikola-Milovic), based on my current projects and my goals, what would be an interesting and challenging thing to do if I am not hired by anyone? I don't care about the complexity, I want to become a great Android developer, so it doesnt even have to be a project, but a good book or source code or anything that can keep me busy untill I find someplace to work in.

Comment: You haven't finished college yet, right? Do you plan to? Is there an internship/job placement office at the college?

Comment: @JoeStrazzere well hobby doesn't cut it but I haven't worked in a company, so something inbetween. I am preparing for the industry. And yeah it's been around 10 days for some applications and with Coronavirus job market I am doubtful that juniors are needed as much as before.
\n

mkennedy I plan to finish it while working as well. I can make a deal with the college for attendance and I'll study in my free time. I am not sure about internship/ job office yet, but I plan to ask about it next week.
\n

Thank you both!

Comment: Why don't you focus on finishing school? I understand the urge to start as soon as possible, but you only have so many hours in the day.  Imagine yourself as the potential employer who looks at your application and sees that you are in school right now; he will assume that you will have to spend a big portion of your day on lectures, homework, etc. For some positions, that is simply a no-go. For others (e.g. internships) it's OK.

Comment: I kept applying for 7 months as a junior before I could find a job, I must have applied to 200 offers or more, because my field can't be found anywhere, but I found a job. One week is nothing. Keep applying over and over, you'll find something eventually. Don't lose hope, I know a guy who's been applying for more than 15 months before he could find something. Be patient, be calm and keep trying.

Comment: After I got my degree, it was probably hundreds of applications over about 4 years before I got my first development job.  You're just starting the process.

Answer (score 5):

#### Wait until you’ve finished university.

You’re at university. Your job isn’t working, it’s finishing your degree to the highest level you can. Focus on that.

The reason you’re not hearing back from employers is because you’re not even a university graduate yet, and having a university degree is one of the most basic requirements white collar jobs possess.

You might think that you’re at a junior level right now, but you’re not. There’s a lot of stuff you’ve yet to learn, and there’s a notable psychological principle that says that the less capable someone is at a task, the better that they think they are at it because they lack the skills to evaluate themselves accurately.

Answer (score 4):

You do not "prepare for not landing a job." You keep going until you land a job. If I understand your question correctly, you're at college right now. This is great: there are people there whose actual job is helping you find a job. Get them to help you. There are also your fellow students, who are going through the same process as you and probably willing to talk endlessly about selecting the perfect font for your resume or whatever.

If all 15 applications result in a "no thankyou" then you need more applications. In fact, why wait? From now until you're hired, you're looking and you're applying. First you look in the obvious places and apply to the obvious things, but then you keep going. Most people take a LOT longer than a week to get a job.

One thing to consider is widening your net a little. Now that you've learned Android development, could you do iPhone development? Could you do web stuff using whatever the hot framework is this week? Could you learn another language and do some work in that? Imagine a company that wants to hire a junior [whatever] developer and would like to add an Android version of their app some day. They would love to hire you, even though they're not ready to hire an Android developer.

After all, you're not going to be an Android developer until you're 65. Think about all the BlackBerry programmers back in the day, or Windows Phone developers. Think about people who were doing client-server work at the turn of the century. Think about all the .NET developers who are now doing JavaScript stuff instead. They're easy to find. In this industry we constantly change and adapt and the more skills we have, the better. You've learned one kind of programming, but that doesn't mean that's the only kind of job you can look for. Keep looking, keep applying, keep telling people you're looking, and have an open mind about what you take -- you'll find something.

Answer (score 2):

You need to look to the job search and maybe to the start of the career from different angles, here are my tips:

- Improve your marketing skills. Make a good CV, make every detail count, ask HR professionals to go through it, make your GitHub and LinkedIn shine, put a lot of effort into it. I seen a few of your GitHub repositories, I would at least try to improve the readme files, hide the ones you're less comfortable speaking about, etc.
- Improve your coding skills. Google courses, read books, make more projects, try to take certification courses etc, contribute to open source, do volunteering. If there are no jobs now, try to prepare for a time when there is going to be, so you would be ready 100%.
- Ask for professional advise. And while workplace is a good place to start, there are a lot of specifics to your country, city and a career path in general, so ask some people in your circles, the ones who are pretty successfull.
- Do not give up. Times are tough, I know, but you must push forward. A week into a job search and 15 or so job applications filled are just really a start and not the end. People send 100 or sometimes thousands of CV's and still get denied.

Sorry to hear your situation, wish you the best of luck!

Comment: Thank you! Giving up was never an option, unfortunately, these 15 are all I had to send as there are no more options. I've decided to pick up some open source, start my own more challenging projects and start reading up on some books. Will keep me busy.

Comment: Way to go! You will make it!

Answer (score 0):

A good option while you're still in school and learning is to get a tutoring job at the university you're attending. They usually have flexible hours, and you'll get a lot of practice reading, debugging, and explaining code. It won't pay as well as a developer job, of course, but it does pay better than an unpaid internship. You may have to wait until you've finished your freshman year, though; they probably won't allow you to tutor classes you haven't taken yet.